# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number' typescript - grab single key from array

Tags: typescript

I have the following:

```
let x = array[stringKey]
```

where the array is associative. Typescript gives the above error.

How can I simply get the value? I know the string key exists but typescript insists it should be an index

I want to avoid turning off any typescript rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is nothing like associative array in JS, it is called just an object or key->value map to be precise. Array in JS can have only keys as numbers, if you want to have key as string, then you just use an object literal.

```
const someObj: { [key: string]: object } = {}; // key -> object map
const stringKey = 'someKey'
const x = someObj[stringKey] // works
```

Of course you can be more precise (you should) and define some type for whatever this object should contain.